# How to open page in new Tab without button click in vueJs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to open the page link in a new tab after Axios response success, I have googled the solution about it but the browser keeps blocking popup. I have tried the below one but not getting work and not supported in all browsers

`let newTab = window.open(); newTab.location.href = url;`

Comment: are you using adblocker?

Comment: no extensions I have installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_blank` can help you opening new window.
check out the documentation of window.open function on w3school.
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp

But for security reasons, browsers block such pop-ups. This is a default and desired behaviour from user security point of view.
You can override this setting using below solution.
https://blog.getadblock.com/how-to-disable-pop-up-blockers-in-every-browser-a1cccbae53e7

Answer (score 0):

You could specify it as the second parameter with `_blank` value:

```
let newTab = window.open(url,'_blank');
```

Answer (score 0):

@Dhruti if all else fails you can still have a button click trigger the new tab, just make th button hidden and trigger a click action with JavaScript. Give the button an id or ref="somename" in Vue, and a class. Set it's `opacity: 0;` and position it somewhere on the page where it's unnoticed. You could even set `position: relative;` (or absolute/fixed) and give it a `z-index: 0;` or -1, and then after your axios response, call
`this.$refs.hiddenButton.click()` making sure that you've set `target="_blank"` on the button.

*tip,
`target="_blank"` will open a new tab each time that element is clicked.
`target="blank"` (with no underscore) will open a new tab the first time, and then reuse that tab on each subsequent click.

Answer (score 0):

In `Composition API`, it is necessary to create a handler function to get `window` browser object.

```html
<script>
const handleOpenLinkInNewTab = () => {
  // window object is visible here
  window.open('http://google.com', '_blank')
}
</script>

<template>
  <div @click="handleOpenLinkInNewTab">
    <ArrowTopRightOnSquareIcon class="h-4" /> 
  </div>
</template>
```

---

**Note:** In this next example `window` is `undefined`

```html
<template>
  <div @click="() => window.open('http://google.com', '_blank')">
    <ArrowTopRightOnSquareIcon class="h-4" /> 
  </div>
</template>
```